# Posting multipart form data with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, multipartform-data

I'm building a rails app that interacts with a 3rd party API

When a user uploads a file to rails, it should be forwarded on to the 3rd party site via an HTTP POST.

In some cases, the upload can be several hundred MBs.

At the moment, I've just been re-posting to the API using Net::HTTP and accessing the multipart form object like so

@tempfile = params[:video][:file_upload].tempfile

This is hella slow though and feels kinda dirty.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to have the user post directly to the 3rd party service or do you have to handle the API through your Rails stack? Ideally you would be able to do this and would not have to load the file into your stack and then re-post it to the API. If you can't post directly, I would recommend seeing if the API has a streaming service so that you can send parts of the file instead of the entire thing at once.  Either way I think you'll start running into Timeout errors on your side and on the API side with large files, so you'll have to increase your own timeouts or create a different type of streaming file uploader.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I agree with this option...

I need to keep record of the files uploaded on my own DB but the API offers callbacks - I just need to catch the callbacks and create new records with those methinks

Comment: That sounds like a much better option to me. If you can avoid pulling that file into memory you'll have a much more scaleable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Spin up a background job using DelayedJob. In the delayed job, you could try rails redirect_to.

https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/redirect_to

Comment: You mean upload the file to a tmp location on my server and then create a DelayedJob to do the posting in the background and cleanup once it's done?

Comment: I think the intermediate tmp file should not be required.  You could just do a redirect_to with the file.